# $injector:strictdi - Following John Pappas style guide

Tags: angularjs

following John Pappas style guide for a while now. I have hit an issue when creating a directive using the proposed method. I get the $injector:strictdi error but not 100% sure why? If anyone can take a look at the code below and point out what's wrong that would be great!

```
'use strict';

(function() {
angular
  .module('app.components')
  .directive('myAccount', myAccount);

function myAccount() {
  var directive = {
    templateUrl: 'client/app/components/my_account/my_account.html',
    restrict: 'EA',
    controller: MyAccountController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };
  return directive;

  MyAccountController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MyAccountController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.showBtn = false;
    vm.showIt = showIt;
    $scope.$apply();
  }

  function showIt() {
    console.log('Show it');
  }
}

})();
```

Comment: myAccount function doesn't have annotation.

Comment: maybe the $inject should be after the function definition.

Comment: @estus yes that is what the error says.. but it is annotated?

Comment: @gaurav5430 that wont work..

Comment: myAccount is't annotated in your code. And it requires [annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation). This is what strict di mode is about.  You've omitted the actual error message, but I believe it gives enough details on who's the troublemaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI [This github issue shows the same thing](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/108).

Your problem is that you are returning the directive before the injection happens and, therefore, the injection code will be unreachable when you minify it. You should inject before you return the directive.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I was looking around this morning and came across this also!